# How to convert JSON to JSON lines

Tags: json, jsonlines

I am new to JavaScript. I am building an array of objects. I need to stringify it, get rid of the square brackets, and split each object on ',' and put on new line.

Need to go from:

```
[{"product_id":297316,"id":1,"rating":3},{"product_id":98133,"id":2,"rating":2}]
```

To this:

```
"{"product_id":297316,"id":1,"rating":3}",
"{"product_id":98133,"id":2,"rating":2}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by put on a new line you mean print, you can do:

```
for (let product of products) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(product))
}
```

Or if you want to produce a newline-separated string you can do:

```
products.map(JSON.stringify).join('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

So.... I got that you need understand code lines for testing or what information comes from API or something like that.

Most of the time I use replace using regex in Sublime Text 3 in a fast way, like:

[image: Example]

Comment: If you use Google Chrome could use a plugin called JSONView to parse automatically json info. If you want get to a major league you can use Postman.